# Shouldn't 'hotness' be 'heat'?

Tags: discussion, spelling

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this, but this annoys me a bit every time I see it. 'Hotness' is just bad English, surely it should be 'heat'?
I'm British, so perhaps you do things differently over the water.

Comment: Where did you read 'Hotness'? Maybe you want this site: http://english.stackexchange.com/ BTW, I am the hotness! (doesn't work with heat)

Comment: Two upvotes? Really? Hidden Unicorns?

Comment: That term actually does pop up now and then: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hotness+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: I call my wife "Your Hotness" (as opposed to "Highness"), so it's definitely a word!

Comment: I suggest you go watch Men In Black II.

Comment: Just a warning about @Joel's suggestion to watch Men In Black II -- it isn't nearly as good as Men In Black -- but hopefully, with your now-reduced expectations, you can enjoy a silly movie. -- Old-and-busted

Answer (score 12):

Hotness is a word in the English language, which is the noun representing how "hot" something is. It's very commonly used to refer to the instances of "hot" that are *not* related to temperature (which heat generally implies).

In our case, we're using "hot" as in "hot topic", a subject or topic that is on the eyes and minds of a large number of people. Something a lot of people are looking at. While its word origins probably come from the temperature (as have many of the forms of hot), it's still not *quite* as direct, so "hotness" comes out more direct than "heat" in the UI.